# Есть какая-то возможность ускорить этот код?

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy, matplotlib, фракталы

```
def mandelbrot(filename='fractal.png'):
    def get_fractal(pmin, pmax, ppoints, qmin, qmax, qpoints, max_iterations, infinity_border):
        image = np.zeros((ppoints, qpoints))
        p, q = np.mgrid[pmin:pmax:(ppoints * 1j), qmin:qmax:(qpoints * 1j)]
        c = p + 1j * q
        z = np.zeros_like(c)

        for k in range(max_iterations):
            z **= 2 + c
            mask = (np.abs(z) > infinity_border) & (image == 0)
            image[mask] = k
            z[mask] = np.nan

        return -image.T

    image = get_fractal(-2.5, 1.5, 1000, -2, 2, 1000, 200, 20)

    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='flag', interpolation='none')

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(20, 20)

    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig(filename, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Само долго исполняется функция `get_fractal`. Можно как-то ускорить всё это дело через какой-нибудь `numba.njit`, `multiprocessing` или что-то вроде этого?

Answer (score 0):

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def draw_fractal(image, z, c, p, q, max_iterations, infinity_border):
    for k in range(max_iterations):
        z = calculate_z(z, c, p, q, k)
        mask = (np.abs(z) > infinity_border) & (image == 0)
        image[mask] = k
        z[mask] = np.nan

    return image
```

Получилось написать такую функцию, но вот проблема.

```
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(array(float64, 2d, C), array(bool, 2d, C), int64)
 
There are 10 candidate implementations:
   - Of which 8 did not match due to:
   Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
     With argument(s): '(array(float64, 2d, C), array(bool, 2d, C), int64)':
    No match.
   - Of which 2 did not match due to:
   Overload in function 'SetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba\core\typing\arraydecl.py: Line 171.
     With argument(s): '(array(float64, 2d, C), array(bool, 2d, C), int64)':
    Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
      TypeError: unsupported array index type array(bool, 2d, C) in [array(bool, 2d, C)]
  raised from C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\arraydecl.py:69

During: typing of setitem at D:/Islam/Python/Islam/test/test.py (16)

File "test.py", line 16:
    def draw_fractal(image, z, c, p, q, max_iterations, infinity_border):
        <source elided>
            mask = (np.abs(z) > infinity_border) & (image == 0)
            image[mask] = k
            ^
```

Comment: calculate_z это отдельная функция, также ускоренная через jit(nopython=True) и она работает отлично, проблема не в ней